# Referrals > Commitments: In Soviet Russia, commitment refers you?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase, referrals

Take a look at [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4300/roblox). Notice anything strange? (if you didn't, try using [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)'s search facility, keyword "Roblox").

[image: What is this I don't even know]

**That's right, the number of referrals (133) is greater than the number of committments (115)!**

Furthermore, one user has referred MORE people than there are committed users:

[image: 119 > 115. Also, I need more referrals]

### WHAT???

Comment: Does it still count as a referral if somebody commits and then uncommits?

Comment: Looks like this John Sheldejeajkeauga guy is a wizard.

Comment: @Sid: Not really. The site is targeted at users of an online game, for which John Sheldejeajkeauga is a developer. So his referral link is on the official website.

Comment: John Sheldejeajkeauga is a man on a mission: *Crash the IE6 browsers of anyone clicking the `186 referred` button.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed!  We don't count commitments until the user verifies their email address (to avoid artificially inflating commitment counts), but we were not doing the same for referrals.  Now, a referral only counts if the user verifies their email.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer people during the **definition** phase:

[image: Referral link]

You sure those referrals aren't from before the commitment phase began?

Comment: I was pretty sure that referrals during the definition phase weren't counted. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Eric that is correct, but we stash the data in a cookie so if they commit later you can still get credited with a referral