# Why do some sites require more commitments than others to launch?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Area 51 Commit Percent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent)

For example, [Writers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623?phase=commitment) launched with just over 200 commitments, but [Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism) has more than twice as many and is only at 54%.  What determines how many commitments are needed for a site to launch?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70552/impossible-to-launch-site-with-all-new-users-on-area-51